Exponential of linear operator as solution to linear matrix ODE?
For $X_0 \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C}) $ and $A$ a linear operator from $\mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C}) $ to $\mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$.
We consider the following matrix valued ODE problem :
\begin{align*}
X'(t) &= A[X(t)]\\
X(0) &= X_0 
\end{align*}
Can we say that the solution is given by $X(t) = \exp\{tA\}[X_0]$ ? Where $ \exp\{tA\}[Y] = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{t^{k}A^{k}[Y]}{k!} $ ?

Yes, we can, at the very least in the case of a time-independent operator $A$.

The answer is YES.
In fact, the exponential $\mathrm{e}^{tA}$ of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ (complex, in general), is alternatively defined as the unique, and globally defined, solution of the IVP, corresponding to $n^2\times n^2$ linear system of ODEs
$$
\mathscr X'=A\mathscr X, \quad \mathscr  X(0)=\mathscr I,
$$
where $\mathscr X$ is $n\times n$ matrix and $\mathscr I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.
Hence, $(\mathrm{e}^{tA})'=A\mathrm{e}^{tA}$, and if $X_0$ is an $n-$dimensional vector, then $(\mathrm{e}^{tA}X_0)'=A\mathrm{e}^{tA}X_0$. Consequently, $X(t)=\mathrm{e}^{tA}X_0$ is the unique solution of the IVP
$$
X'=AX, \quad X(0)=X_0.
$$

It's still true if $\mathfrak{A}$ is a linear operator not necessarly a matrix for example $\mathfrak{A}[X] = LXL - X$ where $L$ is matrix ?

Yes. The $LXL-X$ can be written as $AX$, where $A$ is an $n^2\times n^2$ matrix.
